# Direct image of sheafs

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, holomorphic-bundles

I am trying to understand the definition of direct images of sheafs in Hitchin lecture notes. Here $f:\tilde{M} \rightarrow M$ is a holomorphic map between Riemann surfaces. My problem appears in the proof for (2) in the case of not regular values.

[image]

[image]

I don't understand why a section of $L$ has then to look this way.

My thoughts: we can say $h(z)=h(f^{-1}(w))=h((z^kg(z))^{-1}(z^k))$. Is that the correct ansatz?